# How can I know if such value exists in database? (ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, ado.net

For example, I have a table, and there is a column named 'Tags'. I want to know if value 'programming' exists in this column. How can I do this in ADO.NET?

I did this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Tags='programming'", conn);
OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better version, it is a good practice to use parameters instead of string concatenation, see [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 1
 FROM table1 WHERE Tags=?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Programming";
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(rdr.Read())
    // record exists
else
   //Not exists
```

Answer (score 5):

use SELECT COUNT(*) and check the results.
 (and use ExecuteScalar)

(assuming you know how to set the connection and use it)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 1
FROM    table1
WHERE   Tags='programming'
```

Comment: This solution is better to your's or Dani's because the server will stop processing as soon as it encounters one row with the right tag. If coloumn is not indexed , this will prevent a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

You should do two things:

If you are just checking the presence of a tag called Programming, you should change your query to return a COUNT instead of returning all rows.

`SELECT TOP 1 Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Tags = 'Programming'`

You should check the returned set in the reader to see if there are any rows. If there are, then it means that the tag exists.